# Windows default application switcher by Logitech mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, logitech-setpoint

I've a logitech M705 mouse and downloaded Logitech's Setpoint software for customizing it.

I can set custom keystrokes for buttons, and I'd like to set <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> for choosing between open programs, however I can't do it as when I press the key the application loose the focus as Window's application selector is opened and activated immediately.

Is there any way to set it?

I've tried searching for that, however the links I've found were all broken.

Comment: I'm sorry but is it not implied in the action of _"changing program"_ the acquisition of the focus from the new program chosen? ps> Any help from this [`LockSetForegroundWindow`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7431117/3569208) answer?

Comment: @Hastur yes. I've updated it, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Yes it is... but you can do better `;-)` (I still have some doubts). Once it started, it is supposed you should use the arrows keys or the mouse to cycle among the possibilities(maybe the mouse wheel)... maybe you can associate a different sequence of commands to your button. Give it a look [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/get-more-from-windows-7-alttab-app-switching-tricks-you-didnt-know-about/) if there's something suitable for you. Good luck. BTW with `ESC` you should be able to gain back the focus on the original window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around a bit I've found the solution:

- Select button; select task: "Keystroke assignment"
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, this will enter `Ctrl + Alt +` to "keystroke" textbox and give focus to Windows's application selector
- press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to setpoint
- pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> will add `Tab` to the exising code:)

[image]